# How do I check if a string, converted to lowercase, is equal to something in Bash Code?

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
echo "Write the name Alfred."
read usrinput
#if [ "$usrinput" -eq "Alfred" ]
```

What I want to check is if the string "usrinput", converted to
lowercase, is equal to, in this case, "alfred".

How would I do that in Bash?

Comment: In bash, `read` can issue a prompt: `read -p "Write the name Alfred: " usrinput`

Comment: `-eq` is for numerical comparisons; use `=`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `,,` syntax @janos suggests is only available in newer versions (4 and higher) of bash. In older versions, try:

```
if [[ $(perl -pe 's/(.*)/\L$1/' <<< $usrinput) = alfred ]]; then
...
```

This will also work:

```
if [[ $(tr A-Z a-z <<< $usrinput) = alfred ]]; then
...
```

although `tr` syntax varies between flavors and versions of Unix, so you may need to read the `tr` man page for the exact syntax on your system.

Comment: `tr A-Z a-z` is POSIX-compliant.

Comment: @janos Thanks for the edit, I've been using various shells for so long I sometimes forget the new, fancy stuff. :-)

Comment: Thank you! You're a lifesaver.

Answer (score 5):

In Bash 4+, you can use `,,` to convert a variable to lowercase,
and then you can compare the result of that to the lowecase target string that you want.

```
if [[ ${usrinput,,} = alfred ]]; then
    # do something
fi
```

Comment: Well, it just says "bad substitution"

Comment: Bash 4+ just for the record.

Answer (score 3):

`bash` can do case-insensitive matching:

```
shopt -s nocasematch
if [[ $usrinput == alfred ]]; then
    echo "$usrinput matches"
fi
shopt -u nocasematch
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tr [:upper:] [:lower:]` to convert from uppercase to lowercase. For example:

```
$ echo "foo BAR" | tr [:upper:] [:lower:]
$ foo bar
```

Then you can use it inside your 'if' condition...